# User control with ajax fails to load in smart part with ajax

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I have a user control with some ajax functionality. I am using smart part  with ajax to load user control. I have put this user control in my virtual directory i.e(C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\2323\UserControls). But while loading it is giving me an error as follows

Error: unable to load ~/UserControls\Vendors.ascx

Details: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uriString

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply try to load my user control with ajax functionality in to simple smart part and not in smart part with ajax and it works..i don't know how..but the user control get loded successfully and the ajax functionality is also working fine...

Thanks